# Powershell output formatting table

Tags: powershell, formatting, output

I have a line of script

```
`Connect-hpoa *servername* |get-HPOAServerName |format-list -property Hostname,ServerName`
```

that gives the following output:

```
Hostname   : gblonblade1 ServerName : {@{Bay=1; ServerName=Absent;
SerialNumber=; Status=; Power=; UID=; Partner=}, @{Bay=2;
ServerName=GBLON1234.ops.test.net; SerialNumber=123456789          
Status=OK; Power=On; UID=Off; Partner=}, @{Bay=3;
ServerName=GBLON5678; SerialNumber=987654321; Status=OK; Power=On;
UID=Off; Partner=}, @{Bay=4;ServerName=Absent; SerialNumber=; Status=;
Power=; UID=; Partner=}...}
```

how can i change the output to view just the Hostname and server name and bay number?

```
Hostname   : gblonblade1
Servername: Absent
Bay=1
Hostname : gblonblade1
Servername: gblon1234.ops.test.net
Bay=2
etc....
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, and can you give more background on your `connect-hopa` function such as what it does?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Get-HPOAServerName` produces a property `ServerName` that contains a list of hashtables (which is what your output looks like), you could transform the output like this:

```
... | Get-HPOAServerName | % {
  $hostname = $_.hostname
  $_.Servername | % {
    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $_ |
      select -Property *,@{n='HostName';e={$hostname}}
  }
}
```